# @react-three/cannon hooks changing value of matrixAutoUpdate to false

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber, cannon.js

I'm having some difficulty getting my camera to follow an object. The object is using a hook useSphere from @react-three/cannon. My sphere moves around fine, but the camera does not follow. Ive narrowed it down to my sphere position is not being updated because matrixAutoUpdate gets set to false. I'm unsure why this is happening because on other examples of Cannon that I tested matrixAutoUpdate stays true. Any ideas would be awesome, I have been stuck for a while and can't find anything on internet. Below is some code

```
import React from "react";
import {useFrame, useThree} from "@react-three/fiber";
import {useKeyboardControls} from "../hooks/useKeyboardControls";
import {FPVControls} from "./FPVControls";
import {Vector3} from "three";
import {useSphere} from "@react-three/cannon";

const SPEED = 6

export const Player = (props) => {
    const {camera} = useThree()

    //sphere movement controls
    const {
        moveForward,
        moveBackward,
        moveLeft,
        moveRight,
        jump
    } = useKeyboardControls()


    const [ref, api] = useSphere(() => ({
        mass: 1,
        type: 'Dynamic',
        ...props
    }))


    useFrame(() => {
        camera.position.copy(ref.current.position)
        const direction = new Vector3()

        const frontVector = new Vector3(
            0,
            0,
            (moveBackward ? 1 : 0) - (moveForward ? 1 : 0)
        )

        const sideVector = new Vector3(
            (moveLeft ? 1 : 0) - (moveRight ? 1 : 0),
            0,
            0
        )

        direction
            .subVectors(frontVector, sideVector)
            .normalize()
            .multiplyScalar(SPEED)
            .applyEuler(camera.rotation)

        api.velocity.set(direction.x, 0, direction.z)
    })

    console.log("ref position", ref)

    return (
        <>
            <FPVControls/>
            <mesh ref={ref}>
                <sphereGeometry  />
                <meshStandardMaterial color={"#f30707"} />
            </mesh>
        </>
    )
}
```

Comment: maybe this can help you :
https://discourse.threejs.org/t/get-the-position-of-the-falling-object-react-three-cannon/28542
i've hade a similar issue with my position not being updated by using cannon hooks, the key is to subscribe to the api position and store it in a ref as from what i understood

Comment: @codeanjero Thank you this put me on the right track. I was able to basically do the above example and assign values to the new camera position based on the subscribed values. Thanks a ton!

Comment: No problem. I've put my previous comment in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this helpful on a similar problem maybe it can help you :

[a conversation about a similar issue](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/get-the-position-of-the-falling-object-react-three-cannon/28542)

This similar issue is about a position not being updated by using cannon hooks, the key is to subscribe to the api position and store it in a ref as from what i understood.

Here is a more precise example in the AI component (line 69, you can find the ref on line 79):

[usage example](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-three-cannon-racing-game-starter-klj34)